# Retrieve from DB value stored by INSERT trigger immediately after it executes

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger

In an SQLServer DB, a table exists (A) with an INSERT trigger on it. In that trigger, when a record is inserted into (A) a value is inserted/updated in another table (B).

A program using an ADO Recordset executes an INSERT into (A) by using AddNew/Update ADO Recordset methods. How safe is to try and read the value stored in table (B) immediately after the Recordset.Update is called on table (A)? Taking into consideration that this whole process is enclosed within a Transaction, is there *any* chance the "SELECT FROM B" statement is executed before the server has a chance to execute the "INSERT INTO B" statement from the trigger (for instance, on high-load of the server)?

Comment: Note that even if it's transactionally safe, relying on a trigger to update the seemingly unrelated table B will result in code that will appear quite mysterious, and is possibly a maintenance problem. Consider using a stored procedure instead -- even if the trigger is necessary for other reasons (like applications that can't be updated), at least *new* code can make its intentions clear that way.

Comment: Basically, in the specific case i'm working on at the moment, i've done just that. In the trigger i'm just settings the parameters for the stored procedure and call it. Seemed more clear that way.

Comment: My point is that code that does `INSERT A; SELECT * FROM B WHERE...` looks illogical from the client side, since there's no hint that there's been a specific change to `B`. If instead it called `InsertWidgetWithFrob` and the stored procedure did `INSERT A; -- Trigger on A has filled B bla bla; SELECT * FROM B WHERE...` the database-specific logic is contained entirely within the database, and the whole thing looks like one logical operation on the client side. Separation of concerns thing.

Comment: I see your point. The problem in this case is that i'm trying to workaround a problem and that's the best way i've found so far that does not involve massive alteration of the existing application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggers execute synchronously, as part of the statement that caused them to fire. There is no risk that a following statement will execute before the trigger has completed its actions, unless the trigger is doing something to deliberately decouple its actions from the original statement - such as by using service broker to queue some form of change.

Assuming your trigger is not using service broker but is just performing a direct `INSERT` into table `B`, you're entirely safe.